# Javascript Slideshow not working when using LocalStorage

Tags: javascript

I have a slideshow in JS and html which works fine until I use a variable stored in localStorage to define which slide to start from when the page refresh/reload.

What works:
 - after the page has reloaded, the slideshow starts from the desired slide;
 - after the page has reloaded and after the first command forward, the slideshow begins to work correctly.

What does not work:
 - after the page has reloaded, moving the slideshow forward for the first time always makes the slideshow begins from the first slide;
 - after the page has reloaded, moving the slideshow backward for the first time always makes the variable in the local storage undefined and the slides disappear.

I think the issue is with the showSlides(), but I cannot understand what it is.

Here is my code so far:

```
// Set local storage
var slideIx = localStorage.getItem('slideIndex');
if (slideIx === null) {
    slideIx = 1;
}

var slideIndex = slideIx;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    localStorage.setItem('slideIndex', slideIndex);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('slideIndex'));
} 

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    localStorage.setItem('slideIndex', slideIndex);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('slideIndex'));
} 

// Show slides
function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
} 

// Arrows control
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        e.preventDefault();
            plusSlides(-1); //left <- show Prev image
    } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        e.preventDefault();
            plusSlides(1); // right -> show next image
    }
};
```

Thank you very much for any hint you might have(!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you need to convert string to number before you operate with it. The value retrieved from localStorage is always of a String type, while you expect number in your code. Try this:

```
var slideIx = Number(localStorage.getItem('slideIndex') || 1);
```

(then next check for `null` is not needed).

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded the slideShow to show the last picture after refreshing the page by the next code (you can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/mu9otwcy/1/):

```
var myIndex;
            if(localStorage.getItem('slideIx') === null){
                myIndex = 0;
                }
            else{
                myIndex = localStorage.getItem('slideIx') -1;
                }
            console.log(myIndex);
            carousel();

            function carousel() {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            myIndex++;
                console.log(myIndex);
                if (myIndex > x.length) {
                        myIndex =  1;
                }

                x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
                var slideIx = localStorage.setItem('slideIx',myIndex);
                setTimeout(carousel, 3000);
            }
```

Comment: This also works, but @dfsq's answer was preferred for pointing out the issue and fixing it with one line of code.